# I like a proposed site, but it has a duplicate… follow both?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Just search "skepticism", "French", or "Spanish" on Area51. Each has at least two identical or nearly-identical proposals (and both Skepticism ones are on the verge of entering the commitment phase). They all have comments referencing their twin, but so far nothing seems to have been done to actually merge them.

Is it better to "pick a winner" and follow it (hoping to divert the split attention), or just go with the flow and follow both? What happens if both start up?

**:edit:**

Some links:

[Skepticism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6993/skepticism)

[Skeptic Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptic-exchange) (though this one was created later, it was proposed by the existing SE 1.0 site at http://www.skepticexchange.org)

*

[English/French Translation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation)

[French-English Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11183/french-english-exchange)

*

Here are a few Spanish ones, too, though you could easily argue their exact purposes may be different enough to warrant them not being merged:

[Spanish Translators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15089/spanish-translators-traductores-de-espanol)

[English to Spanish and Spanish to English Translation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18687/english-to-spanish-and-spanish-to-english-translation)

[Spanish Language and Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-and-usage) (this one seems more akin to the [English Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage) site for grammar geeks rather than a multi-lingual resource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those proposals that are duplicates are in the process of being closed. What I would suggest is seeing which one was created first and following that one.

The others are likely to be closed as duplicates. In fact, if you supply me with links, I'll cast some close votes for obvious dupes.

Comment: Sure thing.  For the sake of formatting and sanity, I'll edit them into my question.

Comment: There. I voted to close a couple of those.